# Tensorflow: how training data is processed if batch_size x train_steps is greater than number of records?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Let's say I have training set of 1000 lines, batch_size is 100 and train_steps is 12. As i understand in this case csv will be read 12 times by 100 lines each time? But there is only 1000 lines, not 1200. But from my small experience I can set train_steps to any number like 100000 and training will pass fine. So does it mean that csv will be read from the beginning each  10th step?

```
def generate_input_fn(filenames,
                  num_epochs=None,
                  shuffle=True,
                  skip_header_lines=0,
                  batch_size=200):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer( filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=shuffle)
  reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)

  _, rows = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue, num_records=batch_size)

  features = parse_csv(rows)
#
# shuffle=false 
#
  features = tf.train.batch(
    features,
    batch_size,
    capacity=batch_size * 10,
    num_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
    enqueue_many=True,
    allow_smaller_final_batch=True
  )
  return features, parse_label_column( features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN) )
```

It's based on census example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census

Comment: The answer depends on how you read your data, we'll need to see the corresponding code to answer

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 0):

At each epoch you'll start again reading your CSV files from start, but they will be re-shuffled between each epoch by [tf.train.string_input_producer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) (note that the order of the files will be shuffled, not their content). Although it would be better to have a big enough dataset so that you don't need the same data twice, it's actually very rare that you do have such a big training set, so using the same data several (or even a lot of) times is usual and still works well (up to a certain point).

Comment: So am I correct that training set is **always** read from the start to the end per epoch and this does not depend on train_steps param, but evaluation directly depends on eval_steps ( number of csv rows read === eval_steps )? In generally,  how tensorflow use train_steps parameter? Does it process each batch train_steps times, then takes next batch and trains it train_steps times and so on until csv end and this is called one epoch? I don't use num_epochs params, does it mean that csv is processed once? (  shuffle is false always and only one training file with about 200k records used )

Comment: Btw, when setting eval_steps=None evaluation never stops,  though due to docs I expect that eval csv should be read from the start to the end simply. Sorry for so many questions, just trying to understand internal dynamics of TF concerning input reading

Comment: The set is always read from the start if all your data is in one file. If it's in several ones, they're shuffled each time (the files order is, not their contents). `train_steps` basically counts the batches. During training, you'll read `batch_size*train_step` csv rows, so you have to make sure that this number is lower than `total_rows_csv*num_epochs` in your input reader; or that `num_epochs=None`, it'll cycle indefinitely through your data. You'll train on the whole data once (so for `train_steps=total_rows_csv/batch_size`), that is 1 epoch, then it'll go again over the same data, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Does same logic apply to evaluation?

Comment: yes it works similarly. If you set `eval_steps=None`, it should read the entire evaluation set once.

Comment: as I wrote for some reason it does not stop evaluating if eval-steps=None

Comment: Then we'll need your full evaluation code, and it's probably better to put it in a new question.